# Changing CSS3's translate while retaining other values?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element that has `-moz-transform` applied to it with `translateX()`, `translateY()` and `skew()`. What I need to do is to alter the `skew()` value without touching the translations, using javascript.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general solution:

```
var elem = /*...*/

var transformations = getComponentsFromAttribute(elem.style['-moz-transform']);
transformations.skew = [1, 1];

elem.style['-moz-transform'] = getAttributeFromComponents(transformations));
```

Using these functions:

```
function getComponentsFromAttribute(attribute)
{
    var componentMap = {};

    var regex = /([a-z]*)\(([^)]*)\)/gi;
    var matches;

    while(matches = regex.exec(attribute))
        componentMap[matches[1]] = matches[2].split(/, */);

    return componentMap;
}

function getAttributeFromComponents(componentMap)
{
    var componentList = [];

    for(var key in componentMap)
        componentList.push(key + '(' + componentMap[key].join(',') + ')');

    return componentList.join(' ');
}
```